# bpmn js - export svg to bpmn xml

Tags: node.js, xml, express, bpmn, bpmn.io

I have tried multiple ways to export the svg from the modeler to a bpmn xml, but unable to export.
I tried following ways

1. `modeler.moddle.toXML(modeler.get('canvas'), { 
           format: true 
    }, function (err, updatedXML) {
           console.log(updatedXML);
   });`
2. `modeler.saveXML({
           format:true
   },function(err,output){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           }
           else{
               console.log(output);
           }
   });`
3. `cli.save('bpmn');` - It works on the browser console.

I always get these: undefined or no definitions loaded.

Please help.

Comment: Which modeler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

The main problem was my thinking.
As I come from a background of PHP type languages that are synchronous; so even though I read about the mean stacks asynchronous nature, I wasn't applying it.

Later I applied the same code and it worked.